# char* change when applying a function

Tags: c, substring, c-strings, function-definition

I am trying to implement a function which transform a `char*` of the form `[name]` into `name`.
Here is my function :

```
char* rmChar (char* tagName){
    char* newName = tagName;
    newName++; //remove first character
    unsigned long len = strlen(newName)-1;

    if (newName[len] == '\n'){
        newName[len] = 0;
        newName[len-1] = 0;
    }
    else{
        newName[len] = 0;
    }

    return newName;
}
```

What I don't understand is that if I apply my function on a variable of type `char*` it will modify it. 
For example if I run the following code :

```
char test[] =  "[test]";
printf("%s", rmChar(test));
printf("%s", test);
```

then it prints out : `test[test`

I don't understand why the variable has been change into `[test` ? 
is there a way to modify my function rmChar such that the variable `test` is unchanged ?

Thank you !

Comment: You have to write to a different array or print differently, maybe in a loop with the start and end index.

Comment: The `else` branch is executed, and there you delete the `]`, you can limit the number of chars printed in `printf` (`test` instead of `[test]`) using  `printf("*s", strlen(test - 2), test + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing `char*`, you are passing the place that the string exists, not the string itself.
Therefore, modifying the string will modify the original string.

To avoid this, you can copy string before modifying.

example fix:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for using malloc() and free() */

char* rmChar (char* tagName){
    /* copy input string */
    static char* copiedStr = NULL;
    free(copiedStr);
    copiedStr = malloc(strlen(tagName)+1);
    strcpy(copiedStr, tagName);
    /* and edit it */
    char* newName = copiedStr;
    newName++; //remove first character
    unsigned long len = strlen(newName)-1;

    if (newName[len] == '\n'){
        newName[len] = 0;
        newName[len-1] = 0;
    }
    else{
        newName[len] = 0;
    }

    return newName;
}
```

This function allows throwing returned pointer away like `printf("%s", rmChar(test));`
with minimum memory leak, but is not safe when it is used from multiple threads.

Comment: Since the function is called only once in the OP's code, there is a memory leak (the return of `rmChar()` is never freed)

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes there is, but its harmness will be small because second call of `rmChar()` will free previous returned buffer.

Comment: How do you know how big is the leak? a string of 10000 bytes can be passed :P

Comment: Since you are using a `static` you can call `free(rmChar(""));` at the very end, not a nice API but at least it doesn't leak.